# Passing objects to an ArrayList Java

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am trying to pass 5 objects of 3 types into an array list. When I print the list all values are zero. I've tried amending the object types but still no result, can anyone help?

```
//Item is a Class by itself and the 5 objects draw from this but will have 2/3 additional parameters
ArrayList<Item> inventory = new ArrayList<>();

//Item 1
 Dvd dvd1 = new Dvd(1234567, 2001, "Sugar were going down", "15", "Comedy DVD", 2, 180, "Japanese");

//Item 2
 Dvd dvd2 = new Dvd(7654321, 2005, "The only way is up!", "12A", "Comedy DVD", 3, 220, "Greek, Spanish, Italian");
```

And so on.. Now my output looks like this:

```
ID: 0
Year: 0
Title: 
Classification: 
Genre: 
Return Date: 25/5/2014
Available: true
```

Any Suggestions?

Code for Adding Objects:

```
 inventory.add(dvd1);
 inventory.add(dvd2);
```

Print Code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<= inventory.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(inventory.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing how you're printing things out?

Comment: Please add the code of your output and the insertion of the items

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question and add the relevant content.

Comment: please edit your question and please show me the toString() method of your DVD class

Comment: share your Item and Dvd source

Comment: Can you post the code for the constructor(s) for the Dvd class?

Comment: What happens when you try System.out.println(dvd1); ? This will tell you whether the problem is with retrieving from your list or (as I suspect) the problem is with printing your dvd info.

Comment: Also, your for-loop condition is wrong, you shouldn't call `inventory.get(inventory.size())` so `i` should be strictly lower than `inventory.size()`

Comment: no `i< inventory.size()` in loop check corrects that

Comment: seems only default values are getting printed

Comment: KathyA You were right, it is successfully passing the information when the objects are declared as an Item, but when the other classes extend from that they are not being saved with any of the details!

Answer (score 0):

Your DVD Class should override the toString() Method and there you will have to create the String you want to see in your output.

```
public class ....
.....
    public String toString() {
        return "I am a DvD";
    }
}
```

this would return "I am a DvD" each time you call system.out.priontln(inventory.get(i));

That means you will do something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
sb.append("ID: " + <IDVariable>);
sb.append("\nYear: " + <YearVariable>);   //<<<< \n means new Line
....
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: From the sample output provided - it looks like this has already been done.

Comment: Hi, Getting closer, i wasnt able to add the toString code to the question as when copying and pasting im getting an error, ive re written the toString and its now passing the Date Returned and availability (Not shown) and still not giving the information about the DVD's

Comment: Are your Strings okay? maybe you messed up the constructor and some remained empty. Also try to set a breakpoint in your toString() so you can debug in there and see whats going on  if you are using eclipse just double click a line at the left side (a blue dot appears) then click the bug instead of the normal run button. 
you will be able to see what values your Strings hold and maybe you can figure out whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

As you have the Dvd class make the 8 fields that have initialized in the constructor as private then implement the getters for those fields

Then in the implmentation class create the arraylist as :

```
List<Dvd> inventory = new ArrayList<Dvd>();
```

then add the objects initilized to the list.
Then you can obtain the values from the list by iterating the list as :

```
for(Dvd dvd : inventory)
```

`dvd` will give you the `dvd` objects then just call the getters on it

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved, simple mistake, failed to call super()

=/